# Error on sonar-maven-plugin when analyzing csharp projects

Tags: maven-plugin, sonarqube

I got an error when analyzing csharp projects in sonar 3.1.1
It fails to execute sonar-maven-plugin. Here is my log file data.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.0:sonar (default-cli) on 
project MyProject: Can not execute Sonar: Error occured while reading Visual Studio files.   
Could not evaluate the expression com.sun.org.apache.xpath.internal.jaxp.XPathExpressionImpl@ec73b9 on project
D:\projects\MyProject\src\framework\MyPro\MyPro.csproj: XPathExpressionException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.XIncludeAwareParserConfiguration
cannot be cast to org.apache.xerces.xni.parser.XMLParserConfiguration -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read   
the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVE/MojoExecutionException
```

please help me to solve this issue...

Comment: Can you specify which version of the C#/.NET plugins you are using?

Comment: i am using sonar-dotnet-plugin-2.1.

Comment: Impossible, this version han't been released yet...

Comment: sorry.. it's my mistake. its 2.0

Answer (score 0):

You have probably added an extra JAR that is messing up the classpath. You should try to make a fresh install and everything should be OK.